# Score as a maximum inner fields score

Tags: elasticsearch

It's possible to set every field `_score` as a maximum score from `inner_hits` score?

Example:

```
{
  "_index": "index",
  "_type": "alias",
  "_id": "AViSPf6GaurMMeQ9qGiW",
  "_score": 0.95593464,
  "_source": {
    ...
  },
  "inner_hits": {
    "tags": {
      "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 1.1711202,
        "hits": [
          ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to set `_score` as a `max_score` from `inner_hits`, so in this case `_score` should be 1.1711202.